# modification for stoplimit type for ruleSignal

Tags: r, quantstrat

I wonder if anyone could help me modify my stoplimit (stop loss) rule. How can I change it to sell with close below limit price, rather than low below limit price?

```
> #rules add.rule(strategy.st, name="ruleSignal", 
>          arguments=list(sigcol="buyTrigger", sigval=TRUE, ordertype="market", 
>                         orderside="long", replace=FALSE, prefer="Open", 
>                         osFUN=osDollarATR, tradeSize=tradeSize,
>                         pctATR=pctATR, atrMod="X"), 
>          type="enter", path.dep=TRUE,
>          label="newEntry")
> 
   add.rule(strategy.st, name="ruleSignal", 
         arguments=list(sigcol="buyTrigger", 
                        sigval=FALSE, 
                        ordertype="stoplimit", 
                        orderside="long", 
                        replace=FALSE, 
                        orderqty='all',
                        order.price=quote(mktdata$loss.stopLimit[timestamp]),
                        orderset="orders"),
         type="chain",
         parent="newEntry",
         label="takeProfitLong",
         path.dep=TRUE)
```

Comment: Well, I just found the original code that determines the type of stop: if(procorders[[ii]]$Order.Price>Lo(mktdata[timestamp]). I found the quantstrat package in my R library, but I can't find any of the actual code in there. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the source and opened the tar.gz folders to modify ruleOrderProc.R.

Uninstalled and reinstalled the package. After a few tries, I was able to modify the code to read:

```
if ((orderQty > 0 && orderType != "stoplimit") || 
                    (orderQty < 0 && (orderType == "stoplimit"))) {
                    if ((has.Cl(mktdata) && orderPrice > as.numeric(Cl(mktdataTimestamp)[, 
                      1])) || (!has.Cl(mktdata) && orderPrice > 
                      as.numeric(getPrice(mktdataTimestamp, prefer = prefer)[, 
                        1])))
```

...